# Why i am getting : (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:2244 error

Tags: linux, apache, webserver

When i start apche server i am getting error like

```
[root@ram conf]# service httpd start
Starting httpd: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ram
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:2244
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:2244
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

I am running it as root user .
How can i fix this ?

Comment: there's something wrong with the address, If I'm not mistaken: `0.0.0.0` is reserved. .. That and, check if the socket is not in use?

Comment: [This answer suggets SELinux](http://serverfault.com/a/580281/50264) as the culprit.

Comment: No its not CentOS . It is Redhat. @dusan.bajic

Comment: But in my httpd.conf i define like
Listen 192.168.2.2:2244 and 
<VirtualHost 192.168.2.2:2244> 
-----   </VirtualHost>
-----

Answer (score 0):

When `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` is configured so httpd listens on a port other than TCP ports 80, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, or 8443, the `semanage port` command must be used to add the new port number to SELinux policy configuration.

```
semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 12345
```

Run `service httpd start` again to start httpd and have it listen on the new port.

From [The Apache HTTP Server and SELinux](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Confined_Services/chap-Managing_Confined_Services-The_Apache_HTTP_Server.html)